# iOS stops launching my Xamarin.iOS app to process incoming push notifications

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.iOS app that registers with an Azure notification hub to receive push notification. When the app is running in the foreground or inactive, but showing in the task manager, notifications are received, processed and stored. When the app is not running and has been removed from the task manager, iOS will launch the app and fire the DidReceiveNotification event so the notification can be processed and stored in the app’s database.

Unfortunately, after an hour or so, iOS will receive an incoming notification, which appears on the lock screen, but my logging shows it no longer launches the app to process and store the notification. Anyone have an idea why?

I am using the following for this app:

- Visual Studio 2019 16.9.4
- Xamarin.Forms 5.0.2012
- Xamarin.Essentials 1.6.1
- Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.iOS 3.1.1
- Physical iPhone 11 Pro running iOS 14.5
- Push Notifications Capability checked in the App Identifier on the Apple Developer site
- Enable Background Modes and Remote Notifications capabilities are enabled in the Info.plist

Comment: Do you mean when you close the app,you could not launch it after click the notificaition ?

Comment: When the app is not running, DidReceiveNotification is not firing for the notification to be processed and stored.

Comment: You could check if it fire the `FinishedLaunching` method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I was able to check when FinishedLaunching is called by the OS with a non-null option parameter and store the notification in the app. Thanks Leo Zhu!